# What is \bfd in ConTeXt?

Tags: context, context-mkiv

This is found fairly often in examples, but I found no explanation what `\bfd` actually is. It is never mentioned in the manual. So, what is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All the different font switches are explained on the [Font Switching page](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Font_Switching#Font_sizes) in the [Garden](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/).

To answer your question, `\bfd` selects bold face in the font size corresponding to the factor `d`, by default d = 2.074.

You can look up all the default values for these factors in [`font-pre.mkiv`](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/beta/tex/context/base/mkiv/font-pre.mkiv#L397).